# ipad 3.2.2 loading in landscape

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I changed the properties in info.plist to support orientation in landscape thereby the app opens in landscape mode as well. The problem which i face is like when the app loads in landscape mode the view is properly aligned. There is a view on the right side of the split view is not aligned properly. But when i load that in the portrait mode and then into landscape there are no issue. Can you tell me if there are additional properties or some work around for this issue.

Comment: are u using split view controller in a tab bar controller?

Answer (score 2):

as you are using splitview controller you should not worry about orientation.

just see in your view .nib file there is one **authosizing** feature set that properly u will remove this problem.

This [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling) [may](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW1) help you if you dont know about autosizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

add this code...hope it will work...